# How many kernels simultaneously support on Kepler CC3.0/3.5, 16 or 32 (STREAMs)?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, kepler

As we know Fermi support only single connection to GPU, and as written here: http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

> Fermi architecture can simultaneously support
>
> Up to 16 CUDA kernels on GPU

And as we know Hyper-Q allows for up to 32 simultaneous connections from multiple CUDA streams, MPI processes, or threads within a process: http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf

But how many kernels simultaneously support on **Kepler CC3.0/3.5, 16 or 32 (STREAMs)**?

Comment: [Check here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/#concurrent-kernels)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#conurrent-kernel-execution):

> The maximum number of kernel launches that a device can execute
>   concurrently is 32 on devices of compute capability 3.5 and 16 on
>   devices of lower compute capability.